# How can I get a callback when a jquery transition finishes

Tags: jquery, animation, rotation, transition

I have a animation that rotates a needle, It's working as expected, but I'd like to get a callback when my transition finishes. Here is my function..

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {

function AnimateRotate(d){
    $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: d}, {
                duration:1440,
        step: function(now, fx){
            $(".needle").css({
                 transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
            });
        }
    });
}

AnimateRotate(90);

});

</script>
```

This is what I've tried, but neither one fires when the transition completes. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(".needle").bind('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', 
function() { 
         alert( "Finished transition!" ); 
 //do something
});

$(".needle").bind("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", 
    function() { 
         alert( "Finished transition!" ); 
    //do something
});
```

Comment: Use the complete callback to the .animate call.

Comment: Awesome, funny I tried that, but it was getting called before my animation began, just tried it again, and it worked.  Make an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the complete callback to the `.animate` call.

```
function AnimateRotate(d){
    $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: d}, {
                duration:1440,
        step: function(now, fx){
            $(".needle").css({
                 transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
            });
        },
        complete: function(){
            console.log("Hello World!");
        }
    });
}

AnimateRotate(90);
```